# Streamwriter deserialize/readline into a type

Tags: c#, serialization

I've been trying to deserialize a textfile by using streamwriter, the problem i have is that when i deserialize/readline the textfile it only allows me to store it as a string. Fine, I can do that, but ultimately I want it to be a custom type which i have in my program. The purpose is to use streamwriter to write and read from a textfile, so I'm not able to use xml or binary for this purpose.

This is how my methods look like right now, and i'm unsure how to properly add it back into a list. The "obj.add(reader.ReadLine()); gives me an error, by saying I can't convert string into T.

```
public static void TextFileSerialize<T>(string fileName, List<T> list)
{
    StreamWriter writer = null;
    try
    {
        writer = new StreamWriter(fileName);
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
            writer.WriteLine(list[i].ToString());
        }
        writer.Flush();
    }
    finally
    {
        if (writer != null)
            writer.Close();
    }
}

public static List<T> TextFileDeSerialize<T>(string filename)
{

    List<T> obj = null;
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filename);

    try
    {
        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {

            obj.Add(reader.ReadLine());

        }              
    }
    finally
    {
        if (reader != null)
            reader.Close();
    }
    return obj;
}
```

This is what the text document looks  like, after saving.

> Butterfly0         sdfg                                 44                  Female               90 is the size and Flapping is its movement sound
>
> Butterfly1         sdfg                                 44                  Female               90 is the size and Flapping is its movement sound
>
> Butterfly2         sdfg                                 44                  Female               90 is the size and Flapping is its movement sound
>
> Butterfly3         sdfg                                 44                  Female               90 is the size and Flapping is its movement sound
>
> Butterfly4         sdfg                                 44                  Female               90 is the size and Flapping is its movement sound

Comment: Use a serializer/deserializer for this purpose. Whether it's json, xml, or some other format should not matter, unless your goal is to reinvent the wheel in a poor way...

Comment: What exactly are you expecting for behavior? When you say 'textfile' do you mean an actual text file, or JSON? What does this text file look like?

Comment: https://gyazo.com/9f98f9643f05f106e4b6e239170ba619 This is what the textfile is looking like.

Comment: Please provide that in the question as text, and not an image.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there any reason why you don't serialize this as JSON using [Newtonsoft.JSON](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json)?

Comment: It's an assignment for my course, and the purpose is learning seralizing with xml, binary and this.

Comment: In that case I'd best not provide any answers ;-)

What I'd recommend looking at if you're genuinely interested in learning are the following function - [string.Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/how-to/parse-strings-using-split), you should also write to your file in a parsable way with a delimiter rather than spaces.

Comment: Also, you're not actually initializing `List<T>` in your `TextFileDeSerialize` method, you only assign `null` so `obj.Add` isn't going to work.

Answer (score 0):

reader.ReadLine() returns type string 
You can't convert a string into a generic type . That doesn't make sense. If I call this method with type , how would you convert a string into an Apple?

Your use case looks strange, but working with what I  have it could be solved with some sort of encapsulation.

```
    public static List<HolderClass<T>> TextFileDeSerialize<T>(string filename)
    {

        List<HolderClass<T>> obj = null;
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filename);

        try
        {
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                HolderClass<T> c = new HolderClass<T>();
                c.stringVal = reader.ReadLine();
                //c.appleVal = whatever
                obj.Add(c);

            }              
        }
        finally
        {
            if (reader != null)
                reader.Close();
        }
        return obj;
    }

    public class HolderClass<T> {
        public string stringVal;
        public T appleVal;

        public HolderClass() {
        }
    }
```

If your intent is to not return a list of objects, I would do something like this.
You could then have the types you wanted to pass as generics be extensions of holderClass.

```
    public static HolderClass TextFileDeSerialize<T>(string filename, HolderClass h)
    {
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filename);

        try
        {
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                h.stringVal.Add(reader.ReadLine());

            }              
        }
        finally
        {
            if (reader != null)
                reader.Close();
        }
        return h;
    }

    public class HolderClass {
        public List<string> stringVal;

        public HolderClass() {
            stringVal = new List<string>();
        }

        //Add whatever functionality you'd want in your original class you had passing in as the generic
    }
```